# Does opening GMail using firefox have something to do with Google knowing all my other stored passwords?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, passwords, gmail

I cannot express or explain thoroughly, but I hope people here would get what I really mean.

Most of my friends told me that Google Chrome definitely know all my passwords when using GMail or saving passwords in chrome password manager. I'm not sure if it's correct, but to be safe, I just switch to firefox since it is open source, unlike chrome who is owned by Google themselves.

My question is: Do I need to open GMail only in chrome and not in Firefox?

Because if GMail is opened and used in Firefox, Google might have the ability to collect the passwords inside Firefox password manager. Is that possible?

Sorry for the silly question.

Comment: Google only "knows" your passwords if you sync your Chrome settings/bookmarks/passwords across multiple devices.

Comment: hi bobSmith: If you are pointing out that Google will only know my passwords when using synch (because Google is the owner of Chrome), what can you say about using sync in Firefox instead? Who else will know my passwords? The owner of Firefox?

Comment: The default option for Chrome is to have Google generate a key to encrypt your synced data. That key is stored on Google server so in theory, they could decrypt your data with it. Firefox (and now Chrome) allow the user to generate their own key to encrypt their sync data. The key is stored on the users computer and not Google/Firefox servers. [Chrome Sync security](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/1181035?hl=en) / [Firefox sync security](https://blog.mozilla.org/services/2014/04/30/firefox-syncs-new-security-model/)

Comment: Hi Bob: Inside the Password Manager, what exactly is encrypted? Is it only the passwords? Or also the Username logins and corresponding websites? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

No, google cannot discover additional passwords saved in your Firefox key vault, unless they worked with Mozilla to create and ship an interface for that purpose, and no one has any good reason to suspect that this is the case.

The only way they potentially "know" this with chrome, is that they control the key generation process used to encrypt data synced to their servers. If you don't use any form of synch, it is unlikely that Google "knows" any of your passwords other than those used for google services.

Comment: Hi Frank, thank you for the clarifications, it helps. So you mean, even if Google owns Chrome, there's no way they could know all my passwords. Unless I used SYNC, that's the only way they could know, right?

Comment: More or less, but with one potential caveat. it us unlikely but strictly possible that Chrome could be sending all your passwords in plaintext to google every time you authenticate with a service. This would be detected quite quickly if it were happening, so I'm reasonably sure that you need not worry, but at the same time, every time you enter a password into an application, there is always the possibility that the application will not use it as safely as you would want/expect. So, yes I believe you are safe if you don't use synch, but that can't be proven either way.

Comment: Great reply. Would you recommend using Firefox Sync instead, (because it is open source, and no one owns it, it is built by the community and the code is available for everyone to check if there is some back doors?

Comment: I personally don't see much value to synch (I like my devices configured differently and like the "seams" in my user experience), but I am a strong supporter of open source when viable, and Mozilla as a non-profit (who doesn't own the worlds largest data business) is more trustworthy in my eyes. OSS is not a panacea, but it certainly helps address transparency issues.

Comment: On last question Mr. Frank: First, to answer your question (Synching): It makes it easy for me transferring to different locations and still have my bookmarks and passwords always available to me on the computers I use. Here's my last question: Inside the Password Managers both of Chrome and Firefox, what exactly there is encrypted? Is it only the passwords themselves, or also the Username Logins and corresponding Sites? Thanks in advance.

Comment: here is some surprisingly detailed info about the Firefox password manager: https://luxsci.com/blog/master-password-encryption-in-firefox-and-thunderbird.html